# Oracle SQL lag function with partition

Tags: sql, oracle, lag, geometric-mean

I have a table which contains year, month, period, region_code, item_code, current_price columns in a mixed order as shown below:

| YEAR | MONTH | PERIOD | REGION_CODE | ITEM_CODE | CURRENT_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 12 | 41 | 2500 | 010111 | 15 |
| 2020 | 12 | 41 | 1500 | 010111 | 15 |
| 2021 | 01 | 41 | 2500 | 030333 | 32.4 |
| 2021 | 01 | 21 | 2500 | 010111 | 17 |
| 2020 | 11 | 21 | 2500 | 030333 | 15 |
| 2020 | 12 | 41 | 1500 | 020222 | 25 |
| 2020 | 11 | 41 | 2500 | 010111 | 15 |
| 2021 | 01 | 21 | 2500 | 030333 | 21.5 |
| 2020 | 12 | 21 | 2500 | 020222 | 25.2 |
| 2020 | 12 | 41 | 1500 | 030333 | 35 |
| 2020 | 12 | 21 | 1500 | 010111 | 15.1 |
| 2020 | 11 | 41 | 2500 | 020222 | 15 |
| 2021 | 01 | 41 | 2500 | 020222 | 19.8 |
| 2020 | 12 | 41 | 2500 | 030333 | 35 |
| 2020 | 12 | 21 | 1500 | 020222 | 25.2 |
| 2020 | 12 | 21 | 1500 | 030333 | 35.3 |
| 2020 | 12 | 41 | 2500 | 020222 | 25 |
| 2020 | 11 | 41 | 1500 | 030333 | 12.9 |
| 2020 | 11 | 41 | 1500 | 010111 | 15 |
| 2020 | 12 | 21 | 2500 | 030333 | 35.3 |
| 2021 | 01 | 21 | 2500 | 020222 | 22.6 |
| 2020 | 11 | 41 | 1500 | 020222 | 15 |
| 2020 | 11 | 21 | 1500 | 030333 | 15 |
| 2020 | 11 | 21 | 1500 | 020222 | 28 |
| 2020 | 11 | 21 | 1500 | 010111 | 65 |
| 2021 | 01 | 41 | 2500 | 010111 | 31 |
| 2020 | 11 | 41 | 2500 | 030333 | 12.9 |
| 2021 | 01 | 41 | 1500 | 030333 | 32.4 |
| 2021 | 01 | 21 | 1500 | 010111 | 17 |
| 2021 | 01 | 41 | 1500 | 020222 | 19.8 |
| 2020 | 12 | 21 | 2500 | 010111 | 15.1 |
| 2021 | 01 | 21 | 1500 | 030333 | 21.5 |
| 2021 | 01 | 21 | 1500 | 020222 | 22.6 |
| 2021 | 01 | 41 | 1500 | 010111 | 31 |
| 2020 | 11 | 21 | 2500 | 020222 | 28 |
| 2020 | 11 | 21 | 2500 | 010111 | 65 |

I want to get previous_price for each item using lag fuction but could not manage to do that. After that i want to calculate current and previous month's geometric mean for each year, month, region_code and item. ANd there will be a TOTAL row for each month for each item. The result table i wanna get look like that: *(I didn't calculate CUR_GEO_MEAN and PREV_GEO_MEAN values for the demo table)*

| YEAR | MONTH | REGION_CODE | ITEM_CODE | CUR_GEO_MEAN | PREV_GEO_MEAN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 11 | 1500 | 010111 | ... | ... |
| 2020 | 11 | 1500 | 020222 | ... | ... |
| 2020 | 11 | 1500 | 030333 | ... | ... |
| 2020 | 11 | 2500 | 010111 | ... | ... |
| 2020 | 11 | 2500 | 020222 | ... | ... |
| 2020 | 11 | 2500 | 030333 | ... | ... |
| 2020 | 11 | TOTAL | 010111 | ... | ... |
| 2020 | 11 | TOTAL | 020222 | ... | ... |
| 2020 | 11 | TOTAL | 030333 | ... | ... |
| 2020 | 12 | 1500 | 010111 | ... | ... |
| 2020 | 12 | 1500 | 020222 | ... | ... |
| 2020 | 12 | 1500 | 030333 | ... | ... |
| 2020 | 12 | 2500 | 010111 | ... | ... |
| 2020 | 12 | 2500 | 020222 | ... | ... |
| 2020 | 12 | 2500 | 030333 | ... | ... |
| 2020 | 12 | TOTAL | 010111 | ... | ... |
| 2020 | 12 | TOTAL | 020222 | ... | ... |
| 2020 | 12 | TOTAL | 030333 | ... | ... |
| 2021 | 01 | 1500 | 010111 | ... | ... |
| 2021 | 01 | 1500 | 020222 | ... | ... |
| 2021 | 01 | 1500 | 030333 | ... | ... |
| 2021 | 01 | 2500 | 010111 | ... | ... |
| 2021 | 01 | 2500 | 020222 | ... | ... |
| 2021 | 01 | 2500 | 030333 | ... | ... |
| 2021 | 01 | TOTAL | 010111 | ... | ... |
| 2021 | 01 | TOTAL | 020222 | ... | ... |
| 2021 | 01 | TOTAL | 030333 | ... | ... |

I have tried to calculate by writing loads of queries but all failed. I am kinda newbie to this field so everything you show/suggest will help me much. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain the logic you mean for "geometric mean".

Comment: "Geometric mean" has a unique "logic", there is no ambiguity about that. Rather, what I am curious about is the **business application** of that concept, as it relates to prices. I never heard of that before.  Apart from that, it would be interesting to see what **you** tried for the `lag()` part (never mind the additional computations for now), since it seems to me that it should be a pretty trivial application. It would only be interesting if you needed to fill in "missing month" data, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Lets assume that item_no=010111 in 2020 in the 4 month for region_code=1500 has 4 current prices like : 14 - 15 - 14 - 16. The geometric mean for this item in that month is 4th root of 14*15*14*16=14.72708618117. In sql it is expressed as exp(avg(ln(column))) i guess. Sorry for the lack of info i gave earlier. I have a set of prices for regions for each items which vary throughout years and months. In a statistical aspect, the change ratio for each item for each region in a specific month of a year can be calculated by geometric mean.

Comment: I taught university level statistics and I don't recall ever seeing the geometric mean of historical prices having any real-life meaning. Geometric mean of rate-of-return factors makes perfect sense, and sometimes the cross-sectional geometric mean of company sizes, for example, may be meaningful. But what is the real-life meaning of the g.m. of historical prices? I have a strong suspicion that the (statistical) application of the concept is deeply flawed. Anyway, this is off topic - it's not a SQL discussion.

Comment: @ince still its not clear what is previous price or previous  geo mean ?

Comment: @eshirvana previous price of (year 2020 month 12 period 41 region 1500 item 010111) is the price value of (year 2020 month 11 period 41 region 1500 item 010111.

Comment: @mathguy i think consumer price index  in some -or most- countries is calculated by using the change rate of geometric means of goods.

Comment: Right, the change in the cross-sectional g.m. of prices (of **different** goods) - that makes sense. It is used similarly in finance - g.m. of market capitalization of **different** firms at one moment in time. But you are talking about the geometric mean of individual prices, of one single good, taken longitudinally (over time). **That** is something I haven't seen or heard of before.

Comment: @mathguy english is not my native language it may cause some misunderstanding. sorry for the situation. I want to see the change ratio of every good montly according to region. For example i have 6 prices for item - lets say slice of cake - in utah as 14-15-16-14-15-16 in May 2020. The price of cake in utah in June 2020 is recorded as 14-14-15-16-16-15. If i want to see the change rate of cake in Utah montly, then i should calculate the g.m. of that cake for May and June. Prices of June is represented in June column but price records for previous month should come from May.

Answer (score 0):

This query should be pretty self-explained and should at least point you to the solution if there are some details that I didn't catch.

```
with geo as (
 select YEAR, MONTH, REGION_CODE,ITEM_CODE, exp(avg(ln(current_price))) CUR_GEO_MEAN   from tab
 group by YEAR, MONTH,REGION_CODE,ITEM_CODE 
   union all
 select YEAR, MONTH, 'TOTAL' REGION_CODE,ITEM_CODE, exp(avg(ln(current_price))) CUR_GEO_MEAN   from tab
 group by YEAR, MONTH, ITEM_CODE)
select 
 YEAR, MONTH, REGION_CODE, ITEM_CODE, CUR_GEO_MEAN,
 lag(CUR_GEO_MEAN) over (partition by REGION_CODE, ITEM_CODE order by YEAR, MONTH) as PREV_GEO_MEAN
from geo
order by YEAR, MONTH, REGION_CODE, ITEM_CODE;
```

You may want to adapt the `LAG` function with a different partitioning and/or order or if you want to account for the missign months.